# Make equidistant copies of linestrings

Tags: r

I have a linestring like the example below. I would like to make 3 copies of this linestring to the right, that are equidistant to the original linestring with a distance of 2.5. Would be great if you could help me out to create these copies!

```
ID <- c(1:5)
long <- c(1,2,3,5,7)
lat <- c(1,4,6,8,9)

a <- data.frame(cbind(ID, long, lat))

line <- a %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "equidistant"? Every `long` should be shift by 2.5 increments (three times?)

Comment: Let me know if that workL 
`line3= seq(2.5,7.5,2.5) %>% 
  map( \(dist) a %>% mutate(long = long +dist) %>% 
         st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) %>%
         dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>% 
         st_cast("LINESTRING") ) %>% 
  list_rbind() `

Comment: Thanks VinceGreg, the answer from Margusl was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a rather similar understanding of "equidistance", we can use GEOS' offset curve through `geos::geos_offset_curve()`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(geos)

ID <- c(1:5)
long <- c(1,2,3,5,7)
lat <- c(1,4,6,8,9)

a <- data.frame(cbind(ID, long, lat))

line <- a %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat")) |>
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# create 3 offset_curves to the right (-x) of `line` 
offset_lines <- 
  lapply(1:3 * 2.5, \(x) geos_offset_curve(line, distance = -x, geos_buffer_params(join_style = "mitre"))) |> 
  do.call(what = c) |>
  st_as_sfc()

# combine original and offsets to a single fsc
lines <- c(st_geometry(line), offset_lines)
lines
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: -1.371708 xmax: 10.3541 ymax: 9
#> CRS:           NA
#> LINESTRING (1 1, 2 4, 3 6, 5 8, 7 9)
#> LINESTRING (3.371708 0.2094306, 4.315524 3.0408...
#> LINESTRING (5.743416 -0.5811388, 6.631048 2.081...
#> LINESTRING (8.115125 -1.371708, 8.946573 1.1226...

plot(lines, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

But if you just need to shift to the right, adding `c(x_offset, 0)` to the geometry should be enough.

```r
lines_shifted <- 
  lapply(1:3 * 2.5, \(x) st_geometry(line) + c(x,0)) |> 
  do.call(what = c) |>
  # append original
  c(st_geometry(line))

lines_shifted
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 14.5 ymax: 9
#> CRS:           NA
#> LINESTRING (3.5 1, 4.5 4, 5.5 6, 7.5 8, 9.5 9)
#> LINESTRING (6 1, 7 4, 8 6, 10 8, 12 9)
#> LINESTRING (8.5 1, 9.5 4, 10.5 6, 12.5 8, 14.5 9)
#> LINESTRING (1 1, 2 4, 3 6, 5 8, 7 9)

plot(lines_shifted, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeeees, the first one was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!